# Enabling or Disabling time_select using id and javascript/jquery in Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

Say I've a time_select in a form like :

```
<%= f.time_select :rtime, :disabled => true %>
```

and I've a checkbox in the same form, like :

```
<%= f.check_box :rtime %>
```

#### How do I write a JS/JQuery script that enables the time_select tag when its checked?

===========================================

## The solution that worked for me:

===========================================

The time_select tag auto-generated ***two select*** fields with auto-generated ids, one for hour and one for mins. I went to the source code of my HTML page and found out the ids of these two auto-generated  fields which were **"trip_rtime_4i"** and **"trip_rtime_5i"**.

So i wrote the javascript for my check_box as follows:

```
<%= f.check_box :rtime, :onclick => "if(this.checked) 
                                     { 
                                      document.getElementById('trip_rtime_4i').disabled = false;
                                      document.getElementById('trip_rtime_5i').disabled = false;
                                     }
                                     else
                                     {
                                      document.getElementById('trip_rtime_4i').disabled = true;
                                      document.getElementById('trip_rtime_5i').disabled = true; 
                                     } " %>
```

This enables and disables the time field on checking and unchecking the checkbox.
Hope this helps :)

Comment: Can you post the HTML that is output by these rails commands? Typically jQuery is written against HTML instead of rails.

Comment: I think I got it. I did the same. Referred to the generated html to find time_select's id and wrote JS for that.

Comment: Can you post your answer here for others who may come across this question?

Comment: But I'm facing a minor problem. My checkbox doesnt work properly...I am able to check and uncheck only once...it kinda behaves like its disabled...i've to click randomly all over the page and suddenly its active again...Any idea what the issue might be?

Comment: Solved it...the checkbox was too small and clicking it with the cursor completely over it was the way to check it...if your cursor was halfway through the checkbox was clicking, the check action did not take place...also setting the class of div containing the checkbox to div class="checkbox" helped. Cheers :)